# How to add superscript in the code and what data type to use?

Tags: solidity, remix

I stated in my solidity code

```
 _name = 'UZAIR™';
```

which gives this error

```
'ParserError: Invalid character in string.
    _name = 'AUREALS™'; 
            ^-------^'
```

Please tell how to fix it

Comment: Get rid of the non-ascii character `™`.

Comment: but I want to add that it is necessary

Comment: Well you can't. Type `string` allows only for ASCII characters.

Comment: then what  data type should i use?

Comment: There's no appropriate data type for it.

Answer (score 0):

The type `string` only allows for characters from the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Just put the trademark symbols in parenthesis, this is [a common thing to do](https://igerent.com/registered-trademark-symbols-types-differences-and-uses).

```
 _name = 'UZAIR(TM)';
```

Same also applies to `(R)` or `(C)` in case you *really* need it in a Solidity string.